# LINQ: Entity string field contains any of an array of strings

Tags: linq, arrays, string, contains

I want to get a collection of Product entities where the product.Description property contains any of the words in a string array.

It would look something like this (result would be any product which had the word "mustard OR "pickles" OR "relish" in the Description text):

```
Dim products As List(Of ProductEntity) = New ProductRepository().AllProducts

Dim search As String() = {"mustard", "pickles", "relish"}

Dim result = From p In products _
     Where p.Description.Contains(search) _
     Select p

Return result.ToList
```

I already looked at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194930/how-do-i-use-linq-containsstring-instead-of-containsstring) but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Since you want to see if search contains a word which is contained in the description of p you basically need to test for each value in search if it is contained in the description of p

```
result = from p in products
           where search.Any(val => p.Description.Contains(val))
           select p;
```

This is c# syntax for the lambda method since my vb is not that great

Comment: Brilliant! It worked. VB syntax is:

search.Any(Function(n) p.Description.ToLower.Contains(n))

Comment: When I try to do this, I get "Unable to create a constant value of type 'Closure type'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context." my "search" is a List<string> and my "description" is also a string.

Answer (score 6):

```
Dim result = From p in products _
             Where search.Any(Function(s) p.Description.Contains(s))
             Select p
```

Comment: Damn you stole my first ever VB.NET answer!  ;p +1 anyways

Comment: @leppie: Yeah, this is one of my few VB.NET answers.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a simple LINQ query, if all you need is to check for substrings:

```
var q = words.Any(w => myText.Contains(w));
// returns true if myText == "This password1 is weak";
```

If you want to check for whole words, you can use a regular expression:

1. Matching against a regular expression that is the disjunction of all the words:

   ```
   // you may need to call ToArray if you're not on .NET 4
   var escapedWords = words.Select(w => @"\b" + Regex.Escape(w) + @"\b");
   // the following line builds a regex similar to: (word1)|(word2)|(word3)
   var pattern = new Regex("(" + string.Join(")|(", escapedWords) + ")");
   var q = pattern.IsMatch(myText);
   ```
2. Splitting the string into words with a regular expression, and testing for membership on the words collection (this will get faster if you use make words into a `HashSet` instead of a `List`):

   ```
   var pattern = new Regex(@"\W");
   var q = pattern.Split(myText).Any(w => words.Contains(w));
   ```

In order to filter a collection of sentences according to this criterion all you have to do its put it into a function and call `Where`:

```
 // Given:
 // bool HasThoseWords(string sentence) { blah }
 var q = sentences.Where(HasThoseWords);
```

Or put it in a lambda:

```
 var q = sentences.Where(s => Regex.Split(myText, @"\W").Any(w => words.Contains(w)));
```

Ans From => [How to check if any word in my List<string> contains in text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874371/how-to-check-if-any-word-in-my-liststring-contains-in-text) by @R. Martinho Fernandes