# How to check if any word in my List<string> contains in text

Tags: c#, linq

I have a

```
List<string> words = new List<string> {"word1", "word2", "word3"};
```

And i want to check using linq if my string contains ANY of these words; Smthng like:

```
var q = myText.ContainsAny(words);
```

And the second, if i have a list of sentences too:

```
List<string> sentences = new List<string> { "sentence1 word1" , "sentence2 word2" , "sentence3 word3"};
```

and also neet to check if any of these sentence contains any of these words!

```
 var q = sentences.Where(s=>words.Any(s.text))....
```

Comment: does it need to contain whole words or just substrings?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use a simple LINQ query, if all you need is to check for substrings:

```
var q = words.Any(w => myText.Contains(w));
// returns true if myText == "This password1 is weak";
```

If you want to check for whole words, you can use a regular expression:

1. Matching against a regular expression that is the disjunction of all the words:

   ```
   // you may need to call ToArray if you're not on .NET 4
   var escapedWords = words.Select(w => @"\b" + Regex.Escape(w) + @"\b");
   // the following line builds a regex similar to: (word1)|(word2)|(word3)
   var pattern = new Regex("(" + string.Join(")|(", escapedWords) + ")");
   var q = pattern.IsMatch(myText);
   ```
2. Splitting the string into words with a regular expression, and testing for membership on the words collection (this will get faster if you use make words into a `HashSet` instead of a `List`):

   ```
   var pattern = new Regex(@"\W");
   var q = pattern.Split(myText).Any(w => words.Contains(w));
   ```

In order to filter a collection of sentences according to this criterion all you have to do is put it into a function and call `Where`:

```
 // Given:
 // bool HasThoseWords(string sentence) { blah }
 var q = sentences.Where(HasThoseWords);
```

Or put it in a lambda:

```
 var q = sentences.Where(s => Regex.Split(myText, @"\W").Any(w => words.Contains(w)));
```

Comment: I'd go with linq. You aren't escaping control characters in the regex.

Comment: The searching of a catentated string is different to 3 discrete searches, as the start and end word boundaries merge and may produce a false match.

Comment: thnx for your answer but can u advise me in case the words container is a datatable ?

Comment: Warning if using .contains() inside of LINQ with EF Core 8 - [Contains in LINQ queries may stop working on older SQL Server versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/breaking-changes#contains-in-linq-queries-may-stop-working-on-older-sql-server-versions)

Answer (score 6):

```
var q = words.Any(w => myText.Contains(w));
```

To return all the sentences that contain 1 or more of the words:

```
var t = sentences.Where(s => words.Any(w => s.Contains(w)));

            foreach (var sentence in t)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sentence);
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

For your first condition

```
List<string> words = new List<string> { "word1", "word2", "word3" };
string test = "word1";
bool isFound = words.Contains(test);
```

For your second condition

```
bool isFound = sentences.Any(x => x.Split(new char[] { ' ' }).Contains(test));
```

As an unrelated side-note

You are changing the question's scope after getting some answers and that is not a good way to ask questions. :)

Comment: `words.Contains("This string has word1")` will be false, but should be true ("[...] if my string contains ANY of these words.")

Answer (score 2):

While most of the solutions presented are functional (the all call `Contains`, which will give you the desired solution), if the list and the text are large, you may have performance issues.

From the problem that was stated, I'd think that you call a word anything between spaces or any other divisor. So, I'd recommend you split your `myText` into a list of words, and compare each one of them to you list of words, now using contains.

It's way more complex, of course; You'd have to make sure split words correctly -- but with larger strings (for example, a text file) there might be some performance gain.