# How to check a string for words in sequence

Tags: c#, string, string-matching, string-search

So my code looks like this

```
string order = "Im sending you big apples x100";
string[] fruits = { "apples", "big apples", "oranges" };
string[] vegetables = { "tomatoes", "carrots", "cucumber" };

string[] words = order.Split();

if (fruits.Any(w => words.Contains(w)))
{
  //do things here
}
if (vegetables.Any(w => words.Contains(w)))
{
  //do things here
}
```

I want to be able to find depending on the order string what exactly is it if its possible, now in my case when the string array has 2 words in sequence this code doesnt work, how can i do it when my string array has 2 words. I want to find only if it has "big apples" i know i could do it only "apples" but i want to find sequence words in the order string.

Comment: You eliminated the ability to find phrases such as "big apples" in `order` when you Split() `order` into chunks on the `space` delimiter.  If you're looking for an alternative to Regex, you could leave the `order` string intact and search it for the occurrence of substrings. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're searching for a substring you don't need to split the `order` string into individual words. You can use the `String.Contains` method (in this case, replace `words.Contains` with `order.Contains`).

```
if (fruits.Any(w => order.Contains(w)))
{
  //do things here
}
if (vegetables.Any(w => order.Contains(w)))
{
  //do things here
}
```

If your search can be case-insenitive, you can use the `IndexOf` method.

```
if(fruits.Any(w => order.IndexOf(w, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0))
{
   //do things here
}
if (vegetables.Any(w => order.IndexOf(w, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0))
{
   //do things here
}
```

As per comment, this will match substrings of words (e.g. `apple` will match `apples`). If it has to be whole words only then you can use the `regex` in Govind Kumar's answer (which looks to have been copied [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4874391/187697)). You'd use it like this:

```
var fruitWords = fruits.Select(w => @"\b" + Regex.Escape(w) + @"\b");   
var fPattern = new Regex("(" + string.Join(")|(", fruitWords) + ")");
var fruitMatch = fPattern.IsMatch(order);

var vegWords = fruits.Select(w => @"\b" + Regex.Escape(w) + @"\b");   
var vPattern = new Regex("(" + string.Join(")|(", vegWords) + ")");
var vegMatch = vPattern.IsMatch(order);

if(fruitMatch)
{   
   //fruit matched
}
if(vegMatch)
{
   //veg matched
}
```

Comment: Will it check for 'Big apples' and 'apples' both

Comment: `big apple` will match `big apples` because its a substring of it. I've updated the answer to include a regex version which will match whole words.

Answer (score 0):

```
var escapedWords = words.Select(w => @"\b" + Regex.Escape(w) + @"\b");

var pattern = new Regex("(" + string.Join(")|(", escapedWords) + ")");
var q = pattern.IsMatch(myText);
```

Answer (score -1):

This will let you loop through each type of fruit and then check the value. Since you already have an approach which uses Lambda syntax, I thought I'd share a non lambda version!

```
    foreach (var fruit in fruits)
    {
        if (order.contains(fruit))
        {
           //do things here
        }
    }
    foreach (var veg in vegetables)
    { 
        if (order.contains(veg))
        {
           //do things here
        }
     }
```

Comment: I don't see how this solves the problem - behaves exactly like the OP's code