# Check if string is in list

Tags: c#

I am creating a chat filter and i want to remove any potential bad words. I have a list of strings which gets populated by a text file. I then allow the user to enter their message and i want to check if their message contains a bad word from the list i have made. The issue i have is that the code simply doesn't work. The boolean 'isBadWord' always returns valse. Can anybody help me with this please.

I have made sure the text document loads correctly and the list does populate with the words which are not allowed.

```
void CheckMessage(string messageToSend)
{


    bool isBadWord;
    if (purgeWords.Contains(messageToSend.ToLower()))
    {
        isBadWord = true;
    }
    else
    {
        isBadWord = false;
    }


    if (isBadWord == true)
    {
        print("badword");
        StartCoroutine(ClearMessageBadWord());
    }
    else
    {
        SendText(messageToSend);
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume that `messageToSend` is the _complete_ message and not just a single word of it?

Comment: Are the purgeWords also converted to lower case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if any word in my List<string> contains in text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874371/how-to-check-if-any-word-in-my-liststring-contains-in-text)

Comment: What is "purgeWords"? Why do you think, that "purgeWords" contains the (whole) messageToSend?

Comment: @streamlinemessageToSend is the complete sentence as a string. Even if the sentence contains a bad word i want to disallow the entire sentence

Comment: You probably wanted messageToSend.ToLower().Contains(purgeWords)...but this is also not ok :) you can iterate through purgeWords and check if messageToSend contains some word from purgeWords

Comment: @JeffRSon purgeWords is the list of words that aren't allowed. messageToSend is the message the user has typed. I want to check to see if that message contains any words which is in purgeWords

Comment: Yes, sure. But you need to check, if messageToSend contains (any word of) purgeWords.

Comment: WHERE are you checking EACH “word” in the message? `if (purgeWords.Contains(messageToSend.ToLower()))` … is checking if the WHOLE message is one of the purged words, which will always return false. It looks like you need to loop through EACH word in the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think that the `CheckMessage` method would simply RETURN `true` if there were no bad words found. I recommend you alter the method to return true/false depending on if a bad word is found in the message. Something like below…

```
private bool MessageHasBadWord(string messageToSend) {
  string[] wordsToCheck = messageToSend.Split(' ');
  foreach (string word in wordsToCheck) {
    if (purgeWords.Contains(word.ToLower())) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

This method splits the message on SPACES to get each word. Then simply loop through those words and check to see if any of the words is one of the bad words and simply return true if a bad word is found or false if not found. A call to this method may look like….

```
if (MessageHasBadWord(messageToSend)) {
    MessageBox.Show("Message has a bad word");
  }
  else {
    MessageBox.Show("Message is OK no bad words found");
  }
```

Below is a small and complete winforms example... Drop a `TextBox` onto a new form and a `Button` to check the message in the text box.

```
List<string> purgeWords = new List<string>();

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private List<string> GetPurgeWords() {
  List<string> pwords = new List<string>();
  pwords.Add("BadWord1".ToLower());
  pwords.Add("BadWord2".ToLower());
  pwords.Add("BadWord3".ToLower());
  pwords.Add("BadWord4".ToLower());
  pwords.Add("BadWord5".ToLower());
  return pwords;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (MessageHasBadWord(textBox1.Text)) {
    MessageBox.Show("Message has a bad word");
  }
  else {
    MessageBox.Show("Message is OK no bad words found");
  }
}

private bool MessageHasBadWord(string messageToSend) {
  string[] wordsToCheck = messageToSend.Split(' ');
  foreach (string word in wordsToCheck) {
    if (purgeWords.Contains(word.ToLower())) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  purgeWords = GetPurgeWords();
}
```

Comment: I THINK ive added this code right but it still doesnt work. Is this code correct?

EDIT: I cant add the code as its too long -.-

Comment: @Jamie McClenaghan ... please check my updated answer with a complete winforms example.

Comment: The only issue i have now is this. When i update the document with other words it wont work. The old words still work, just not the new ones. However, the list does say there are new words in it

Comment: What do you mean by… _”When i update the document with other words it wont work.”_ ?  what “document”? Are you not checking messages? You need to clarify this.

Comment: EDIT: Forget what i said. I fixed the issue. The issue i have is that this works for the very first message i send. If i send a bad word it works fine but for every bad word i send after that (even its the same as the first bad word) it doesnt work and still send the message

Comment: I am not following you, if you “update” the `purgedWords` `List` with added words, then these new words will also be checked with any “subsequent” call to the `MessageHasBadWord` method. So, I am not sure what does not work. Can you give an example?

Comment: John. I have finally fixed it. I used break points to find more information. In my document i have each back word on their seperate line. The words i tested were:

cat
dog
red
hello

When using break point i found that these words were saved as:

cat\r
dog\r
red\r
hello

For some reason. I simply added a check for the \r part and it works fine. Its a reall weird one. Though it works now

Answer (score 2):

As `messageToSend` contains the complete sentence you want to check, you have to do something like this:

```
using System.Linq;

if (messageToSend.Split(' ').Any(word => purgeWords.Contains(word.ToLower())))
{
    isBadWord = true;
}
```

This way it is checked whether the list contains any bad word and not if the list contains the sentence as whole.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your checking if the badwords contains the message but you actually need to check if the message contains any badwords.

One easy way is to use linq.

```
var lowerCaseMessage = messageToSend.ToLower(); 
var containsBadWord = purgeWords.Any(badword => lowerCaseMessage.Contains(badword));
```

example:

```
    class Program
    {
        static List<string> purgeWords = new List<string> { "badword", "anotherBadWord" };
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var message = "a string containing badword";
            Console.WriteLine(CheckMessage(message));
        }

        static bool CheckMessage(string messageToSend)
        {
            var lowerCaseMessage = messageToSend.ToLower();
            return purgeWords.Any(badword => lowerCaseMessage.Contains(badword));
        }
    }
```

Result: `True`

Comment: one easy way would be to use linq 
`var lowerCaseMessage = messageToSend.ToLower(); var containsBadWord = purgeWords.Any(badword => lowerCaseMessage.Contains(badword));
`. You could also use RegEx to detect or replace the bad word.

Comment: I've just tried this code and it still doesnt work. Thats if i coded it right


void CheckMessage(string messageToSend)
    {

        var lowerCaseMessage = messageToSend.ToLower();
        var isBadWord = purgeWords.Any(badword => lowerCaseMessage.Contains(badword));


        if (isBadWord == true)
        {
            print("badword");
            StartCoroutine(ClearMessageBadWord());
        }
        else
        {
            SendText(messageToSend);
        }
    }

Comment: is your badwords list in all lowercase?

Comment: Yes mate. They are all lower case

Comment: I just wrote a quick test which works perfectly. I'll include it in the answer for comparison.

Comment: I get the error 'An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MessageFilter.purgeWords' on the variable purgeWords

Answer (score 0):

The `purgeWords` is a collection while the `messageToSend` is the string in which the presence of any element (say word) of `purgeWords` needs to be checked. So your `if` condition should do this instead:

```
if (purgeWords.Any(word => messageToSend.ToLower().Contains(word)))
{
    isBadWord = true;
}
else
.
.
.
```