# Like with or conditon in Linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a scenario where i want to search multiple values and with like.
For example:
If i have a sequence like

> ```
> string[] codeValues={"Anthrax","anth","coliblex"};
> ```

And i want to search like '%Anthrax%' or "%anth%" or "%coliblex%".
Currently i am having this code which only returns the values that will match with the exact 
search value.

```
string[] codeValues = {"anthrax"};
var obj=(from icdcodes in M_ICD_CPT_CODEs
where icdcodes.ROW_STATUS==1
      && icdcodes.FK_USER_ID==0
      && icdcodes.FK_CODE_TYPE_ID==240000     
      && codeValues.Contains(icdcodes.CHAR255)
      && icdcodes.MODULE_PHYS_PREF==0
select new 
{
  PkId=icdcodes.PK_ICD_CPT_CODE_ID,
  CodeValue=icdcodes.CODE_VALUE,
  Narrative = icdcodes.CHAR255
}).ToList();

Console.Write(obj);
```

Is there any solution that will filter with like.
Equivalent **sql** will be 
where CHAR255 LIKE '%anthrax%' or CHAR255 LIKE '%someothervalue%'..etc

Thanks

Comment: What database are you using? If you are using SQL Server, you can use a SqlFunctions.PatIndex expression to have the "like" performed at the database directly from your linq expression (i.e. the EF linq provider knows how to do that translation). If you are using a different database, it most likely also has a native "LIKE" clause, but EF will not know how to translate to it. A solution then is to create a stored procedure specific for your database that performs the "LIKE" instruction.

Comment: Thanks Alex.I am using SqlServer 2008.Can SqlFunctions.PatIndex filter for multiple values ?

Comment: Also available is `SqlFunctions.Like`. Both `Like` and `PatIndex` allow multiple matches, wildscards, etc, but constructing the right filter expression may not be that trivial/possible if you try to match a list of keywords. I am not an expert on that subject. I would advise you to check online examples and SQL Server technet docs (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) to see if that will work in your case

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex.I will check them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Any`and`Contains`.

```
string[] codeValues = {"anthrax"};
var obj=(from icdcodes in M_ICD_CPT_CODEs
where icdcodes.ROW_STATUS==1
      && icdcodes.FK_USER_ID==0
      && icdcodes.FK_CODE_TYPE_ID==240000     
      && codeValues.Any(cv => icdcodes.CHAR255.Contains(cv))
      && icdcodes.MODULE_PHYS_PREF==0
select new 
{
  PkId=icdcodes.PK_ICD_CPT_CODE_ID,
  CodeValue=icdcodes.CODE_VALUE,
  Narrative = icdcodes.CHAR255
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks It'sNotALie for the suggestion.I have tried with this .It can work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string[] codeValues = {"anthrax"};
var obj=(from icdcodes in M_ICD_CPT_CODEs
where icdcodes.ROW_STATUS==1
  && icdcodes.FK_USER_ID==0
  && icdcodes.FK_CODE_TYPE_ID==240000     
  && codeValues.Any(val => icdcodes.CHAR255.Contains(val))
  && icdcodes.MODULE_PHYS_PREF==0
select new 
{
  PkId=icdcodes.PK_ICD_CPT_CODE_ID,
  CodeValue=icdcodes.CODE_VALUE,
  Narrative = icdcodes.CHAR255
}).ToList();
```

[LINQ: Entity string field contains any of an array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757214/linq-entity-string-field-contains-any-of-an-array-of-strings)

Comment: Thanks Przemyslaw Kalita.