# LINQ To Datatable using "Any" with a List

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

Okay I just can't get this. I'm trying to loop through a datatable using a list of strings in my where clause, but I'm not able to get it to work.

This is what I'm trying:

```
If d = "IN" Then
    lInOutStrings.Add("Parts in")
Else
    lInOutStrings.Add("Inventory")
    lInOutStrings.Add("Repairs")
End If

For Each part In (From u In dtParts.AsEnumerable() _
                  Where u.Field(Of String)("INVT_TYPE").Any(Function(s) u.Field(Of String)("INVT_TYPE").Contains(lInOutStrings.ToString))
                  Select New With {....}) 

      ...

Next
```

The problem is that the query always returns nothing. What I have I got from [LINQ: Entity string field contains any of an array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757214/linq-entity-string-field-contains-any-of-an-array-of-strings), but I"m not able to complete the query. What is it that I'm doing wrong?

I'm using VB.Net 2010 and .Net 4.0

Comment: try replacing where clause with `Where lInOutStrings.Contains(u.Field(Of String)("INVT_TYPE"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the other way around, look into the list, not into the string (which is an `IEnumerable(Of Char)`):

```
Dim query = From u In dtParts.AsEnumerable() 
            Where lInOutStrings.Contains(u.Field(Of String)("INVT_TYPE"))
            Select New With {....}
```