# Linq to Sql, PredicateBuilder and defining general logic

Tags: linq-to-sql, predicatebuilder

The examples with predicatebuilder show how you can define general logic using predicates. But I'm struggling with the following :

Suppose Product has a foreign key relationship with Category and Category has a DateTime? EndDate.

I can write some general logic to find active categories :

```
public partial class Category
{
   public static Expression<Funct<Category,bool>> IsActive()
   {
      return c=>c.EndDate.HasValue ? c.EndDate>DateTime.Now : true;
   }
}
```

so I can write

```
Categories.Where(Category.IsActive())
```

But I can't seem to make it work when querying Products, I would like to be able to write something like:

```
Products.Where(p=>p.Category.IsActive() && p.Name.Contains("beer"));
```

I could write another method

```
public static Expresision<Func<Product,bool>> IsCategoryActive()
{
   return p=>p.Category.EndDate.HasValue ? p.Category.EndDate>DateTime.Now ? true;
}
```

but I want to avoid defining this logic over and over again... I would be much nicer if I could define this once on Product

Comment: As for the "contains", see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369022/using-contains-in-linq-to-sql.

Comment: the contains is not the problem... it was just an example to show that I need to be able to combine IsActive with other criteria.