# The translation of String.IndexOf to SQL does not support versions with a StringComparison argument

Tags: c#, string, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following code:

```
var items = db.Name.Where(x => x.Forename.IndexOf("john", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0).Take(20);
```

Where `db` is a `System.Data.Linq.DataContext`.

This gives me the lovely error of:

> The translation of String.IndexOf to SQL does not support versions
>   with a StringComparison argument.

All I want to do is compare a string in a database to one entered by a user (in the example above hardcoded as "john") but not take into account the case sensitivity.  I based the code off the following question [Case insensitive 'Contains(string)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369022/using-contains-in-linq-to-sql

Comment: My guess is that the comparison will depend on the collation of the database. So if your database collation is not case sensitive, then the comparison won't be either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help:

```
string test="john";
db.tblUsers.Where (u =>u.Forename.ToLower().Contains((test.ToLower())).Take(20);
```