# How to search if an object has a property with a value C#

Tags: c#, reflection

I would like to create a function where I can pass in an arbitrary object and check to see if it has a specific property with a specific value. Im attempting to do this using reflection, but reflection still confuses me a little bit. I was hoping that someone might be able to point me in the right direction.

here is the code that im trying but obviously it doesnt work:

```
    public static bool PropertyHasValue(object obj, string propertyName, string propertyValue)
{
    try
    {
        if(obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName,BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(obj, null).ToString() == propertyValue)
        {
            Debug.Log (obj.GetType().FullName + "Has the Value" + propertyValue);
            return true;    
        }

        Debug.Log ("No property with this value");
        return false;
    }
    catch
    {
        Debug.Log ("This object doesnt have this property");
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: What "doesn't work"?  Are you getting errors?

Comment: When I pass in an object that I know has both the property and value, it returns my Debug.Log in the catch statement no matter what.

Comment: @MichaelTaylor3D Rather than just printing out that there was an error, you should actually catch the specific execption and log the details of the exception so you know what went wrong (or better yet, don't catch the exception at all if you can't properly handle it).

Comment: It turns out that I was missing a binding flag, Im waiting for the initial 7 mins to be up so I can accept the correct answer. Thanks Everyone!

Comment: Just an FYI, if you're trying to find non-public properties on a secure runtime (say Silverlight) you won't get any. Even with reflection, the Silverlight runtime prevents you from grabbing non-public members.

Comment: Just as an aside - refer to this MSDN page about how to catch specific exception types in a manner which allows you to see an error message - it would appear you're not familiar with that concept. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Intead of catching all kinds of exceptions, you might want to use `GetProperties` and search through the output to see if there's one with the desired name. You could use Linq for that.

Comment: Or even better: Continue using `GetProperty`, but check if its output is `null` (the property was not found) or an `PropertyInfo` instance.

Comment: @tomfanning In this case I didnt care about the exception, I knew that if I received a null reference exception that is was because that object didnt have that property. The try statement is only an attempt to just ignore it if that happened and move on with its life. I mostly kept it in my example in an attempt to show you guys what was going through my head while i was writing this.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I like that Idea, im going to test for that instead of my try-catch.

Comment: @MichaelTaylor3D catching exceptions is not a correct way to do flow control. It's incredibly slow. Refer to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to specify more `BindingFlags` in the `Type.GetProperty` method call. You do this with a `|` character and the other flags, such as `BindingFlags.Public`. Other issues are not checking for null `obj` parameter or null result from your `PropertyInfo.GetValue` call.

To be more explicit in your method, you could write it like this and collapse down where you see fit.

```
public static bool PropertyHasValue(object obj, string propertyName, string propertyValue)
{
    try
    {
        if(obj != null)
        {
            PropertyInfo prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
            if(prop != null)
            {
                object val = prop.GetValue(obj,null);
                string sVal = Convert.ToString(val);
                if(sVal == propertyValue)
                {
                    Debug.Log (obj.GetType().FullName + "Has the Value" + propertyValue);
                    return true;    
                }
            }
        }

        Debug.Log ("No property with this value");
        return false;
    }
    catch
    {
        Debug.Log ("An error occurred.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

In my opinion you should accept `propertyValue` as an `object` and compare the objects equally, but that would exhibit a different behavior than your original sample.

Answer (score 2):

Its too late to answer this question here. But I was searching for the same problem and solved it in a cleaner way with `LINQ` and `Reflection`. So if you are open to `LINQ`. You can get it like this.

```
String propertyValue = "Value_to_be_compared";

Bool Flag = YourObject.GetType().GetProperties().Any(t => t.GetValue(objEmailGUID, null).ToString().Contains(propertyValue));

if(Flag)
{
  //spread love if true
}
```

Code will check if any of the property of you object [Contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369022/using-contains-in-linq-to-sql) the `Value_to_be_compared`

If you want to match exact value then you can go for:

```
Bool Flag = YourObject.GetType().GetProperties().Any(t => t.GetValue(objEmailGUID, null).ToString() == propertyValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

When retrieving members, in addition to specifying instance/static you must specify Public/NonPublic:

For example, to retrieve public properties you would use:

```
GetProperty(propertyName,BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
```

To retrieve all properties you must retrive both Public and NonPublic.

Comment: Reflection can still get the property if it's non-public.  He might want to do this, but I don't see how this is the reason it isn't working.

Comment: The binding flags limit the results, so drop them altogether and you will get the instance.

Comment: When you specify instance you must also specify either public or non public. That is just the way it works. See the sample here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx) and document here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx). Thanks @FlyingStreudel, I was not able to find that.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) and read up about binding flags. In specific:

#### You must specify Instance or Static along with Public or NonPublic or no members will be returned.