# C# Linq - get objects with not empty collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have:

```
private Dictionary<int, Сolor[]> colorSet = new Dictionary<int, Сolor[]>()
{
   {1, new Сolor[2] {Сolor.Red, Сolor.Green}},
   {2, new Сolor[2] {Сolor.Yellow, Сolor.Blue}},
   ...
};

public class Graph
{
   public Сolor Сolor { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Point> Points { get; set; }
}
```

1) How I may get `List<Graph>` from database where `Points` is not empty?

```
List<Graph> graphs = context.Graphs.Where(g => g.Points.Count > 0).ToList()
```

2) How to execute it?

```
List<Graph> graphs = context.Graphs.Where(g => colorSet[1].Contains(g.Color)).ToList()
```

The exception is:

> `LINQ to Entities` does not recognize the method '...' method, and
>   this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Using `g.Points.Any()` will produce more efficient queries than `g.Points.Count > 0`. It lets SQL generate `if Exists(select 1 from ...)` queries instead of `if (select count(*) from ...) > 0` queries

Comment: `colorSet[1].Contains(g.Color)` definitely would not convert to store expression or sql as you are mixing up linq to object with linq to sql. try invoking ToList before where.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya doing the .ToList before the where will cause his entire database to be loaded in to ram on the client. Not usually a good idea.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Ya that's true but it would not work with mix of linq to object and linq to sql. or he needs to create stored procedure for that.

Comment: What is the `Color` class? Is it your own enumeration, an enumeration or an entity?

Comment: Also, which EF version are you using? Enum support was added in EF5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with using [Enumerable.Contains()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) in EF. It's [String.Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that can't be translated.

The problem with your second query is that you mix LINQ operators with object access code, specifically `colorSet[1]`. LINQ to EF will not try to execute this code and doesn't know how to translate it to SQL anyway.

The solution is to store the colorSet value to variable first:

```
var colors = colorSet[1];
List<Graph> graphs = context.Graphs
                            .Where(g => colors.Contains(g.Color))
                             .ToList();
```

LINQ to EF knows to translate `Enumerable<T>.Contains()` to `AND Color IN (0,1)` clause

This assumes that you use at least EF 5,  `Color` is an enum and Point a custom class, eg:

```
public enum Color
{
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue,
    Yellow
}
public class Point
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**

As for the first question, you can retrieve graphs that have any points by using `Any()`:

```
var graphs=context.Graphs
                  .Where(g => g.Points.Any())
                  .ToList();
```

Linq to EF will generate a SQL statement with a `WHERE EXISTS` clause eg

```
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[Points] AS [Extent2]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Graph_Id]
)
```

This will return the graphs that have points but not the points themselves. These will be loaded in a lazy manner when you try to access the `Points` property of a Graph object. This can be a performance gain if you want to access only a few `Points` properties but will result in numerous queries if you want to access all of them (the N+1 problem)

If you want to load the Points as well, you need to use the `Include()` method, eg:

```
var graphs=context.Graphs
                  .Include(g => g.Points)
                  .Where(g => g.Points.Any())
                  .ToList();
```

This will execute a left join between the graphs and points and return all of the data in a single query.

Comment: Not absolutely that is necessary. Selections is executed in big expression. But thks.

Answer (score 2):

.Contains can't be used in the .Where clause of a database context. You can use .Any or .All for comparisons.

```
List<Graph> graphs = context.Graphs.Where(g => colorSet[1].Any(c => c.Color == g.Color)).ToList()
```

See [Using contains() in LINQ to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369022/using-contains-in-linq-to-sql)

Comment: Error: 'Color[]' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Any<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,bool>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Just updated, you need a lambda expression in the .Any and .All methods (or something that returns a bool)

Comment: Actually, `Contains` *can* be used  and results in a ` field IN (X,Y,Z)` clause - as in "I use it all the time with EF". It's the `colorSet[1]` that causes the problem. The link points to `String.Contains`, not `IEnumerable<T>.Contains`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are right. mixture of linq to sql and linq to object would not work anyway.

Comment: It seems, in one step data can't be selected. Thks.

Comment: @Actic, no - it can. You just have to write this properly