# Contains functionality in Linq to XML Where Clause

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

I'm having unexpected behavior with the .Contains() function of the where clause in Linq to XML. It seems to be functioning like "==" not Contains() in the string function.

Example:

```
var q = from sr in SearchResults.Descendants("Result")
    where _filters.Contains((string)sr.Element("itemtype"))
    orderby (string)sr.Element("ipitemtype") ascending
    select new SearchItem
    {
        //Create Object
        ID = (string)sr.Element("blabla"),
    }
```

_filters is a list of strings. Let's say it contains 3 values:

```
_filters[0] = "videos";
_filters[1] = "documents";
_filters[2] = "cat pictures";
```

What happens now, is that the Query works perfectly if

```
<itemtype>videos</itemtype>
```

is the XML node.

However, if the node is

```
<itemtype>videos mission critical document advertising</itemtype>,
```

the IEnumerable returns blank, which to me says the operand is functioning like "==" not "Contains()".

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Winning answer from dtb:

replace

```
where _filters.Contains((string)sr.Element("itemtype"))
```

with

```
where _filters.Any(filter => ((string)sr.Element("itemtype")).Contains(filter))
```

Comment: please review my new answer - the original one was mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
_filters.Any(s => ((string)sr.Element("itemtype") ?? "").Contains(s))
```

This way you're checking that the element's value contains any of the strings in `_filters`. The use of the null coalescing operator ensures a `NullReferenceException` isn't thrown when the `itemtype` node doesn't exist since it is replaced with an empty string.

The other approach is to use `let` and filter out the nulls:

```
var q = from sr in SearchResults.Descendants("Result")
        let itemtype = (string)sr.Element("itemtype")
        where itemtype != null &&
              _filters.Any(filter => itemtype.Contains(filter))
        orderby (string)sr.Element("ipitemtype") ascending
        select new SearchItem
        {
            //Create Object
            ID = (string)sr.Element("blabla")
        }
```

Note that `String.Contains` is case sensitive. So a check for "videos" won't match on "Videos" with a capital "V". To ignore case you can use `String.IndexOf` in this manner:

```
_filters.Any(filter => itemtype.IndexOf(filter, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
```

Comment: The issue I have with this is that <itemtype> may be empty occasionally if the items aren't tagged properly. If an element is empty, i.e. <itemtype />, .Value throws an exception, which is why I always case to string instead of relying on .Value.

Comment: @Wesley try the updated approach. This uses `let` to hold on to the explicit conversion result, which is then filtered out if it's null, then checked against the filter items.

Comment: **EDIT I tried the approach and the Enumeration came out completely empty.

Not true, it came out with some results, but not all.

Comment: @Wesley I added one more update at the bottom of my post before your comment was made. It's possible that either your filters or values contain mixed case. Use the `IndexOf` approach I outlined above to ignore the case of your filters and element values. If that doesn't work then the issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: Ahmad, there was indeed a case problem that was part of poor code from another team. This has been fixed and all the XML has been set to lowercase.

Your solution works, but someone else was a little faster and their code is a little cleaner, so I marked theirs as the answer. I will upvote though, you did a great job.

Comment: @Wesley with due respect to @dtb the solution would break if `itemtype` doesn't exist, causing a `NullReferenceException` to be thrown when `Contains` is called. I had started out with a similar approach then edited it out to clean up the post. I re-added it with another update to address this shortcoming using the null coalescing operator.

Comment: Ahmad, I'm changing yours to the answer, as it is both effective and case insensitive for any possible future mishaps.

Comment: I don't think @dtb's solution will break, as it is using the (string) cast. Unlike sr.Element("itemtype").Value, (string)sr.Element("itemtype") does not cast a NullReferenceException. Either way, I think the case sensitivity issue makes this superior in that sense, but both answers were fantastic.

Comment: where _filters.Any(filter => (string)sr.Element("ipitemtype").IndexOf(filter, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)

I was hoping that would work, but I cannot access IndexOf in this case :)

Comment: @Wesley I meant that in the case of `(string)sr.Element("itemtype")` being null due to `itemtype` not existing, the subsequent call to `Contains` would fail and throw the exception. To use `IndexOf` enclose the cast result in parentheses: `((string)sr.Element("ipitemtype")).IndexOf(...)`. Notice how I've done a similar thing at the top of my post, with parentheses surrounding the cast and `Contains` on the outside of the return result.

Comment: Very Nice. `where _filters.Any(filter => ((string)sr.Element("ipitemtype")).IndexOf(filter, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)` works as a single inline statement, and I tested it with null elements.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if the array `_filters` has an element with the value `"videos mission critial document advertising"` (which is not the case), rather than if `"videos mission critial document advertising"` contains any of the elements in `_filters`.

Try this:

```
where _filters.Any(filter => ((string)sr.Element("itemtype")).Contains(filter))
```

Comment: I don't think that's true, if the node <itemtype> contains a single value like <itemtype>videos</itemtype> then the Linq does return that node, not a string from _filters.

Comment: interesting. So I tried your code and now I have to opposite problem. Nodes that are just <itemtype>videos</itemtype> are being ignored, while nodes like <itemtype>marketing communications videos</itemtype> are being accepted. Truly confused.

Comment: The use of `Contains` here would throw a `NullReferenceException` if the result is `null`. I've updated my response to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are making false assumptions about the way the [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains.aspx) method works.  (Also see the [`String.Contains()` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx)  The contains method returns true if "a sequence contains a specific element".  In the example you described, both the `_filters` array and the `itemtype` text contains the string `videos`, but neither contain each other.  A more appropriate test would be to use the following extension method:

```
public static class ContainsAnyExtension
{
    public static bool ContainsAny<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, params T[] elements)
    {
        if(enumerable == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("enumerable");
        if(!enumerable.Any() || elements.Length == 0) return false;
        foreach(var element in elements){
           if(enumerable.Contains(element)){
               return true;
           }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

So, your correct LINQ query would be:

```
var q = from sr in SearchResults.Descendants("Result")
        where ((string)sr.Element("itemtype")).ContainsAny(_filters)
        orderby ((string)sr.Element("ipitemtype")) ascending
        select new SearchItem
        {
            ID = sr.Element("blabla").Value
        };
```

It may also be helpful to review this post: [How do I use LINQ Contains(string[]) instead of Contains(string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194930/how-do-i-use-linq-containsstring-instead-of-containsstring), which is similar but specifically targets the `String.Contains` method instead of the `Enumerable.Contains` extension.

Comment: .ContainsAny is not an available option for me right now. I'm in Silverlight if that make a difference, but I checked to make sure my .NET framework was version 4.

Comment: @Wesley, what do you mean it is not available?  I posted the code.  Copy and paste it into your solution.

Comment: @smartcaveman this is an awful lot to go through when a simple LINQ statement can get the job done.

Comment: I do, and ContainsAny shows "string does not contain a definition for ContainsAny". I'm looking into this now.

Comment: @Ahmad Mageed You meana  separate LINQ statement. This is what I'm doing right now, but it seems silly to use two statements where one with a proper Where will do.

Comment: @Wesley, (1) After adding code you must build your solution for it to work, (2) The helper class with the extension method must be placed into a namespace that is referenced (by a using statement) from where you are calling it.  An appropriate namespace would be `System.Linq`

Comment: @Wesley one statement will suffice. My updated response does just that.

Comment: @Ahmad Mageed, I agree with you, if this were a one time thing, but this is not an uncommon test condition.  However, @Wesley, you can do `_filters.Any(x=> ((string)sr.Element("itemtype") ?? string.Empty).Contains(x))` if you don't want to use an extension method.

Comment: I cannot build. The message was not an exception but a compile time error. Full error is "Error 9 'string' does not contain a definition for 'ContainsAny' and no extension method 'ContainsAny' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: @Wesley, (1) What is the namespace of the `ContainsAnyExtension` class in your solution?  (2) What type of file contains the code where you are calling the `ContainsAny` method?  (3) Do you see a `using System.Linq` statement somewhere around the top of that file?

Comment: Caveman: Namespace is correct, but there was another error as well which kept this class from compiling. In the second IF statement, the line

    if (!enumerable.Any || elements.Length == 0) return false;

was showing an error for /Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'method group'/

Comment: I would also add that I've selected an answer from above that works. Both Ahmad and dtb had a solution, dtb was just slightly faster.

Comment: @Wesley, that was a typo - I updated my answer.  The correct line is `if(!enumerable.Any() || elements.Length == 0) return false;`  I recognize that Ahmad and dtb have working solutions, the reason I posted this is because it provides a solution that is reusable by the same conventions you are used to.

Comment: I also like the ability to add inline methods. I had never used a solution before that works like this one, and I wish I could mark more than one :) I might ask a second question and post the link back to you on how to do this inline to give you credit for the wonderful work you did.

Comment: @Wesley, the correct term is extension methods and documentation is available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx .

Comment: Fantastic. I was using an old Java method called StringSlice in this project that let's you take a piece of the string from startIndex to endIndex, basically a SubString() method. I had been using it as static string, but this is better, I can now call String().StringSlice