# Search query gives LINQ to SQL exception

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, exception, contains

For the following query I get a LINQ to SQL exception.

```
var terms = "bob town".Split(' ');
var q = from m in db.Monument
    where terms.All(t => new List<string>() {
        m.Name,
        m.Street,
        m.Owner }.Any(
            p => p.Contains(t)))
    select m;
```

The exception is:

> Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query
>   operators except the Contains operator.

How can I modify the query to compatible with LINQ to SQL?

---

**Goal**

The goal of the query is this. I have a list of search terms and a database with objects. An object should be returned if all search terms are substrings of at least one property.

For example. If there is an object `o` with `o.name="creek mill"` and the `o.street="St. Petersroad"`, then a search on "mill petersroad" should return this object, but a search on "mill foobar" should not.

Comment: try jason's answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194930/how-do-i-use-linq-containsstring-instead-of-containsstring/195628#195628 wont that solve your problem?

Comment: You might have some luck at http://blog.wekeroad.com/2008/02/27/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 1):

So, the actual problem is that Linq-To-SQL doesen't know how to convert the `Terms` part of your Linq to a valid SQL statement. So, you have to rejig the query to help it out.

I assume that we would like to use the `Contains` function to get a SQL statement that uses the SQL `IN` operator. Here is what I suggest.

```
var terms = "bob town".Split(' ');
var q = from m in db.Monument
    where 
            terms.Contains(m.Name)
        ||
            terms.Contains(m.Street)
        ||
            terms.Contains(m.Owner)
    select m;
```

I haven't tested this but it looks like it should work and should be converted by Linq-To-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

what about the below. I haven't tried it but it gives you an idea about

```
var terms = "bob town".Split(' ');
        var q = from m in db.Monument
                where m.Name.Split(' ').Intersect(terms).Count() > 0 ||
                        m.Street.Split(' ').Intersect(terms).Count() > 0
                select m;
```

Anyway I think for this kind of search you should think about using SQL Full-Text-search if you got a SQL db or ".net lucene" which fits really well in your context

Comment: We don't want exact text matches, e.g. search "Petersroad" should match "St. Petersroad". Also, all search terms must match at least once. You might be right in saying it is not feasable in LINQ.

Comment: I have edited my answer it should work now.
The "Intersect" will return any intersection of two sequences :-)

Comment: I am not sure this is exactly what he wants. This will return entities that contain terms, but not entities that contain *all* search terms.

Comment: I have edited it.It is just a way to do it. They key is to use the "Intersect" function

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is probably a way to do this with pure `LINQ`, but I am not so sure if it is actually a good idea: IMHO opinion people sometimes tend to overcook their `LINQ` queries for no particular reason other than `LINQ` being very cool and all, ending up with queries that are *very* hard to understand by just looking at them.

Why don't you implement an extension method that takes `Monument` entities and figures out if a certain `string[]` matches your criteria?

That way your `LINQ` expression couldn't get simpler:

```
var q = from m in db.Monument
where m.ContainsAllSearchTerms(terms)
select m; //readable and anyone understands right away what is going on here
```

Being `ContainsAllSearchTerms(this Monument m, string[] terms)` the relevant extension method.

Comment: Your suggestion is very readable, but would it still be converted to SQL? Looping through all entities in C# would probably be too slow.

Comment: I am not sure if that is avoidable no matter how you do it. Maybe you should look into alltogether different options as Massimiliano mentions (SQL full text search, etc.) My advice is try something similar to what I propose, and if performance is horrible then maybe check alternative ways. But my advice is to always check first the easiest path. Premature optimization is normally a bad idea.