# LINQ to SQL with 'Contains' and an INT column. How do you make it work?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm trying to get this LINQ to SQL to work. The problem is parsedSeasons is a string like "1,2,3" and h.season is an int column.  How can I get this to work correctly?

```
  var id = (from h in db.t_ref_harvest_type
                  where parsedSeasons.Contains(h.season)
                  select new { h.id });
```

Comment: you can get this in the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194930/how-do-i-use-linq-containsstring-instead-of-containsstring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first split your comma delimited string like this:

```
var Seasons = parsedSeasons.Split(',').Select(int.Parse);
```

Then use your LINQ query:

```
var id = (from h in db.t_ref_harvest_type
                  where Seasons.Contains(h.season)
                  select new { h.id });
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error...Instance argument: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<int?>'

Comment: Yes, you're right, we forgot to convert the separated elements to ints.  I've edited my answer.  Let me know if there is anything else.