# How to use Contains(Of T)(T) method?

Tags: c#

I have a byte list variable which I store byte array information here:

```
internal List<Byte> portBuffer = new List<Byte>();
```

And I have another byte array variable:

```
byte[] ret_bytes = { 0x4F, 0x4B };
```

How can I find out if ret_bytes is inside the portBuffer? The code below seems like not correct.

```
portBuffer.Contains(ret_bytes)
```

Another question, how to find out the position of the first element of ret_bytes in side the portBuffer list if it is inside the list?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you believe it is not correct?

Comment: Do you want to check the order too?  { 0x4F, 0x4B } != { 0x4B, 0x4F }

Comment: because the VS2010 is showing the errormsg:the best overloaded method "list<byte>.contains<byte>" has some invalid arguments. I think it may be the reason i am passing the byte[] to it, and it cant find any match overloaded function. but how to solve it here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use LINQ Contains(string\[\]) instead of Contains(string)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194930/how-do-i-use-linq-containsstring-instead-of-containsstring)

Comment: thanks. i think it will do the job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Contains` doesn't find one *sequence* within another, it finds one *element* within a sequence - I don't believe there's anything within .NET which will do what you want out of the box.

It's up to you whether you write a very general purpose implementation or one that *just* solves your current issue - the former is likely to be more work, but may pay dividends in the long run.

If you only need to find two bytes, I'd be tempted to just iterate:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (list[i] == 0x4f && list[i + 1] == 0x4b)
    {
        // Got it
    }
}
```

Comment: I could write my own check function, but is there any functions i can directly use? thank

Comment: @gpakillsme: No - as I wrote in my anwer: "I don't believe there's anything within .NET which will do what you want out of the box"

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are correct in your comments, and this has actually already been asked on SO. Can you please verify this is what you are asking :)

[How do I use LINQ Contains(string[]) instead of Contains(string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194930/how-do-i-use-linq-containsstring-instead-of-containsstring)

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ - `IEnumerable<T>.Intersect(IEnumerable<T>)` to get the set of bytes that appear in both `portBuffer` and `ret_bytes`.

```
var portBuffer = new List<Byte> {0x4F, 0x4B, 0x27};
byte[] ret_bytes = { 0x4F, 0x4B, 0x26 };

return portBuffer.Intersect(ret_bytes); // This will return { 0x4F, 0x4B }
```