# How to replace foreach with LINQ expressions

Tags: c#, linq, select, foreach

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use LINQ Contains(string[]) instead of Contains(string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194930/how-do-i-use-linq-containsstring-instead-of-containsstring)

Suppose I have the following **class** and **objects**:

```
class Product
{ 
   public int ProductId { get; set; }
   public string ProductDesc { get; set; }
} 

string[] arrayString = new string []{"A", "B", "C", "D"};

List<Product> products = new List<product>();
```

Is this code:

```
var filteredProducts = new List<product>();
foreach(var searchString in arrayString)
{ 
   filteredProducts.Union(Products.Where(p => p.ProductDesc.Contains(searchString)));
}
```

equivalent to this:

```
var filteredProducts = products.Where(p => p.ProductDesc.Contains(arrayString.Select(s => s).ToString()));
```

If that is not the case, how can the first code snippet be rewritten by using LINQ?

Comment: If your "Product" has only fields describing a "Problem", I don't think I want the products you're tracking :)

Comment: ahahah, I wanted to use my real case but then I figured out that most of the people are acquainted with the product class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the equivalent LINQ form is

```
var filteredProducts = products.Where(p =>
    arrayString.Any(s => p.ProblemDesc.Contains(s));
```

Talking out loud:

> Select all products for which any one of the strings in `arrayString`
>   is contained within the product's `ProblemDesc`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciated also the verbal explanation

Comment: @Jon your solution most likely solves what CiccioMiami actually wanted to know, but it is not equivalent to his first `foreach` sample, since he is reassigning the `filteredProducts ` inside the loo. Not sure if this is an error in the sample of if he performs certain tasks within the `foreach` that he omitted

Comment: @ntziolis: Sure, that's not hard to see. That example code is perhaps a bit misleading, but it's not hard to guess what the idea is here.

Comment: I've just noticed my mistake, I will update the question in case  other users will face the same problem!