# How to use sql IN statement in linq lambda with 2 statements

Tags: c#, linq

My statement is

```
Contents.
    Select(x=> new 
        {
            ContentUsers = x.ContentUsers.
                Where(t=>t.UserId==2).
                Select(t=>t.ContentId)
        }).
    Where(y=>y.ContentUsers.Any())
```

It gives me some Ids that i want to use it my another statements.

[image]

```
Contents.Where(x=>x.Id == 633,634,635)
```

How can i merge them?

Comment: I think this is what you are after: http://stackoverflow.com/a/194974/1373170 
You would have to do the Contains() on the actual array, instead of the other way around.

Comment: Pablo is right. Just do it like you would normally do it in C#. With contains. Same syntax, same functions (to a degree).

Answer (score 1):

What you're missing is the [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338641.aspx) function. It will probably be simpler to express this in a single query expression. If I translate your code to a single query expression, I looks a something like this:

```
var content =
    from c in Contents
    let contentUsers = 
        from x in Contents
        select new
        {
            ContentUsers = 
                from t in x.ContentUsers
                where t.UserId == 2
                select t.ContentId
        }
    where contentUsers.Any(cu => cu.ContentUsers.Contains(c.Id))
    select c;
```

However, it looks like all you want is to get just the `Content` records associated with a given `UserID` in the `ContentUsers` collection. This is a lot easier.

```
var content =
    from c in Contents
    where c.ContentUsers.Any(t => t.UserId == 2)
    select c;
```

or if you prefer

```
var content = Contents.Where(c => c.ContentUsers.Any(t => t.UserId == 2));
```