# Fast multiple string compare

Tags: c#, string, linq

In c# is there a quick way to replace the following with more efficient code:

```
string letters = "a,b,c,d,e,f";

if (letters.Contains("a"))
{
    return true;
}

if (letters.Contains("b"))
{
    return true;
}

if (letters.Contains("c"))
{
    return true;
}
```

I want to do away with having to have three compare lines of code.

Thanks!

Comment: use linq here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194930/how-do-i-use-linq-containsstring-instead-of-containsstring

Comment: what s your use case? where do u get letters or input from?

Comment: `return letters.Contains("a") || letters.Contains("b") || letters.Contains("c")`?

Comment: also why do you have `,` comma's in your test string..?

Comment: Just as an aside to all the answers below (which are all fine), I would suggest you create an extension method or reusable static method to do the work for you and hide the implementation details. Nothing beats your _own_ custom signatures like `letters.HasAny("abc")` or `letters.HasAny('a', 'b', 'c')`, or if the "abc" check is common, `letters.HasABC()` (or whatever name/signature makes the most sense for you). Internally, that extension method implementation can use any of the ideas below, be optimized for speed or maintenance or flexibility, or whathaveyou.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
return letters.Any(c => c == 'a' || c == 'b' || c == 'c');
```

Or this:

```
var lettersToLookFor = "abc";
return letters.Any(c => lettersToLookFor.Contains(c));
```

As per the comments, the last line of the previous code block can be shortened further:

```
return letters.Any(lettersToLookFor.Contains);
```

Comment: Or even: `letters.Any(lettersToLookFor.Contains)`.

Answer (score 4):

If you're literally looking for single characters in a string you can use `IndexOfAny`

```
return letters.IndexOfAny('a', 'b', 'c') >= 0;
```

It makes one pass over the entire string and compares each char in the string against the chars passed in.

If none of the chars exist it's still  M * N comparisons (same as 3 if's above), but if any char does exist it gets out of dodge faster.
Also for longer strings it's kinder on CPU cache memory.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Intersect` to see if there are any characters in common between the two character sets.  Note that strings implement `IEnumerable<char>`, so you can treat all strings as just sequences of characters.

```
bool result = "abc".Intersect(letters).Any();
```

Note that this solution, as it will put all of the characters from `letters` into a `HashSet`, will be dramatically more efficient than the other solutions currently posted that are performing multiple linear searches on the string, assuming the string is of a non-trivial size, and the search characters are not right near the start.  (You did say efficiency mattered.)

Comment: "Dramatically more efficient": This completely depends on the actual string.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution would be to `club three if in single statement` or can use `Any()` like [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18336530/632337) mentioned.

```
if (letters.Contains("a") || letters.Contains("b") || letters.Contains("c"))
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is the way to go.

```
return letters.Any(c => c == 'a' || c == 'b' || c == 'c');
```

Comment: Dam, Daniel beat me by a minute

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = new []{"a","b","c"};
letters.Any(m => arr.Contains(m))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`String.IndexOfAny(Char[]`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11w09h50.aspx) method like?

```
string letters = "a,b,c,d,e,f";

if ((letters.IndexOfAny(new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c' }) >= 0))
{
   return true;
}
```

> The zero-based index position of the first occurrence in this instance
>   where any character in anyOf was found; -1 if no character in anyOf
>   was found.

Comment: >= 0, not > 0. -1 is failure

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression, I couldn't vouch for the efficiency though, you'd have to run a comparison and get timings:

```
return Regex.IsMatch(letters, "[abc]");
```