# Multiple string values to compare with one. something like attributetocheck.Equals(att1,att2,att3)

Tags: c#, sql

I have multiple attributes say att1,att2,att3 which can be separated by any of the separator.
I want to have an "OR" condition in the below query to check if the row value in COLUMN1 is equal or not.
Since .Equals can only have a string ,Can any one suggest any other way of doing it.

```
string result = string.Join(",", attributes);
            List<string> query = (from DataRow dr in response.Output.Tables[0].Rows
                                         where dr["COLUMN1"].ToString().Equals(result)
                                         select dr["COLUMN2"].ToString()).ToList<string>();
```

Comment: You could try `contains` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034503/multiple-string-comparison-with-c-sharp

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336480/fast-multiple-string-compare

Comment: those two are both related. the later even uses linq in its answer

Comment: @christiandev contains helped. thanks a ton.

Comment: @Thomas Linq in the link provided kind of hardcodes it in my code..Help appreciated .....Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Instead of joining attributes to an string, use it's Contains method

```
List<string> query = (from DataRow dr in response.Output.Tables[0].Rows                                         
                      where attributes.Contains(dr["COLUMN1"].ToString())
                      select dr["COLUMN2"].ToString()).ToList<string>()
```

Comment: ..Thanks a lot for the elaboration .Thanks