# How to filter a string[] with LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq, filter

I have the following code:

```
string[] projects = Directory.GetDirectories(dir, "*", SearchOptions.TopDirectoryOnly);
string[] issues = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.txt", SearchOptions.AllDirectories)

foreach (string project in projects)
{
    var filteredIssues = from fi in issues where fi.Contains(project) select new { f = fi };

    foreach(string issue in filteredIssues)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

But this won't compile and gives me the following error:

> Cannot convert type 'AnonymousType#1' to 'string'

I was looking at this example: http://www.dotnetlearners.com/linq/linq-to-string-array-with-example.aspx

And this SO question: [How do I use LINQ Contains(string[]) instead of Contains(string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194930/how-do-i-use-linq-containsstring-instead-of-containsstring)

But I wasn't really sure what `uid` is in that particular case or how to apply the solution to my problem.

I also tried

```
var filteredIssues = issues.Select(x => x.Contains(project)).ToArray();
```

But that returns an array of bools.

`dir` points to a "Projects" folder which will contain N uniquely named folders. Each folder there will contain an "Active" and "Archived" folder containing however many text files (which is what `issues` contains, and I'm effectively just trying to filter `issues` on a Project basis to load them into the UI grouped by project)

Ultimately I want the LINQ equivalent of this SQL statement:

```
SELECT issue FROM issues WHERE issue LIKE '%project%'
```

Although now as I'm writing this I realize I can just simply do `string[] issues = Directory.GetFiles(project, "*.txt", SearchOptions.AllDirectories)` from within the first `foreach` loop rather than outside. But I'm still curious how you could filter a collection of strings based on values that contain another value.

Comment: try `foreach(var issue in filteredIssues){ Console.WriteLine(issue.f); } `

Comment: There's rarely a point of having an anonymous type with only one property. So instead of `select new { f = fi }` you can say `select fi`

Comment: What about: var filteredIssues = issues.Where(x => x.Contains(project)).ToArray();?

Comment: @Dennis_E Thanks, I'm not experienced with LINQ at all so I was unaware I could do that.

Comment: @SimonGates That seems to work, if you want to post it as an answer then I can accept it and close this case.

Comment: @sab669 done, with a little explanation about using Select() :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Where to filter a collection. Like so:

```
  var filteredIssues = issues.Where(x => x.Contains(project)).ToArray()
```

Select is for projecting one `IEnumerbale<Type>` to another `IEnumerbale<Type2>`. Think of it like Mapping, you can cherry pick what to map to the target type.

Answer (score 3):

What you actually want is the text files not in the top level directory.

```
var projects = Directory.GetDirectories(dir, "*", SearchOptions.TopDirectoryOnly);
var issues = projects.SelectMany(p => 
        Directory.EnumerateFiles(p, "*.txt", SearchOptions.AllDirectories));
foreach(var issue in issues)
{
    // Do something;
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Also I might have been unclear, I should say I'm just trying to filter `issues` where the *path* contains Project, not the filename itself. So ultimately if I have ProjectA and Project B, issues might contain `../ProjectA/Active/123.txt` and `../ProjectB/Archived/456.txt`

Comment: @sab669, I see that now, what you actually want is the second half of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

i think you should try this.

```
string[] projects = Directory.GetDirectories(dir, "*", SearchOptions.TopDirectoryOnly);
string[] issues = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.txt", SearchOptions.AllDirectories)

foreach (string project in projects)
{
    var filteredIssues = from fi in issues where fi.Contains(project) select fi;

    foreach(string issue in filteredIssues)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

you should select fi instead of  select new { f = fi };
where 
 **select new { f = fi }** is anonymous type with a string property name as **f**
that is why anonymous type to string conversion failing..