# SQL Select Where In converted to Linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am trying to select from where in out of the database using Linq. The query I would be trying to reproduce is:

```
   "Select * From Avatars Where userId IN (1, 2, 3)"
```

How can this be written in lambda if I have a List of userIds.

I am stuck where the !! are and have a List of userIds:

```
context.avatars.Where(a => a.userId == !!(userIds)!! )
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194930/how-do-i-use-linq-containsstring-instead-of-containsstring

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Contains` method:

```
var result=context.avatars.Where(a => userIds.Contains(a.userId));
```

Or `Any`:

```
 var result=context.avatars.Where(a => userIds.Any(e=>a.userId==e));
```

Answer (score 4):

something like :

```
context.avatars.Where(a => new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Contains(a.userId));
```